# Settings errors in Qt project with OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In the project that use OpenGL in Qt I use in protected method initializeGL() the statement

```
 qglClearColor(qtPurple.dark());
```

Follows errors occurs in the building project:

```
 ‘qtPurple’ was not declared in this scope
 ‘qglClearColor’ was not declared in this scope
```

The files that is included is:

```
 #include <QtGui>
 #include <QtOpenGL>
 #include <QtGui/QColor>
```

In the .pro file is present

```
QT       += core gui, opengl
```

Where are the mistakes that cause these errors?

Answer (score 2):

`QGLClearColor` is a non-static member of `QGLWidget`. So first you must include `<QGLWidget>` to your widget header file and inherit your widget from QGLWidget. Then you will be able to call it in methods of your widget. You get `was not declared in this scope` error because `qglClearColor` is in `QGLWidget` scope.

Alternatively, you can call it as regular method of your widget object.

And what is `qtPurple`? It seems that it's not a part of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>` in your head file.And Your class should inherit `QGLWidget`.
2. It seems that you have not declared the variable `qtPurple`,so check
   your head file,if not exist,just declare it[like this:`QColor qtPurple;`].